# Sending a file from website to C application

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ftp

I have a simple application written in C, and a website built with node/expressjs. The C program is located and run on a separate computer, and on a different network.

Currently no networking functions are in place, but what I want the C program to do is continually receive files from the website. It would have a blocking TCP socket open, and whenever a file is received, it would respond appropriately and handle the file(s). The C program doesn't actively request anything; it just waits. The website (website-user) is responsible for initiating the file transfers, by way of form submission. Both sides are connected via IP address and port.

How can I go about building this sort of communication? I looked into libcurl, and the FTP and SFTP protocols, but I'm thinking they're overkill/inappropriate for this task. Could raw TCP sockets work? The files involved are image files, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw TCP sockets could work, but I don't know if that's what you want to use. It involves lots of low-level setup on your part. Your client application would behave more like a server.

Firstly, it would have to use a listening socket. This would require the client running the application to be a DMZ host or have port forwarding set up for the listening port. If you want to learn how to open a listening socket, [here is a good example](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f00/www/class24code/echoserver.c) that I learned from when making my server. Except I'm not sure why it uses a char buffer… I think uint8_t is more portable, so I use that instead.

Secondly, you would need to establish your own system of wrapping the data you send. As you may know, TCP data is presented as a continuous stream as you call `read`, so you need to make sure your website sends a size header before each file so your application knows when to stop reading. Sending the header in the first 4 bytes will allow you to send files of up to 4GiB (adjust for the desired max file size), but if you need to send files of arbitrary size and aren't worried about malicious connections, use a [variable-length quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) header.

Thirdly, it would need to keep track of how much data is available in the buffer you use with the `read` function, and you need to keep a separate pointer (let's call it `r_ptr`) to the index of the read buffer that `read` should write to. After you process data in the read buffer, you need to shift the rest of the data in the buffer down to the zero index then set `r_ptr` to the byte after the last byte of that data. Next time your program wants to read data, it should only call `read` if the leftover data in the buffer isn't enough, and it should write the incoming data into the space after the leftover data. Otherwise, it may lose incoming data. Consider this situation: Your program waits for 32 bytes to arrive but receives an extra 16 bytes in the last time you call `read`, and those bytes are now somewhere in the buffer and won't ever be received again with `read`.

Lastly, if you want your program to accept multiple connections at once, you may want to handle each client in its own thread. That's the easiest way, but I don't know whether or not it's the most efficient.

Comment: Manual TCP sockets does seem to be the most straightforward way to go. I had little idea if the nature of my task was conventional or unorthodox, so it's nice to know that it's doable with raw socket programming. A very helpful and elaborate post, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's much easier to let the libraries do all the raw socket programming for you ;)